# How to refer to a virtual machine's IP address in a security group - ingress rule (cidr_block) using terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to allow access the virtual machine from my IP addr and the another ec2 instance IP address. So I need to put pub IP of EC2 instance into SG cidr_block. I tried different options and didn`t find any solution:

```
#   cidr_blocks = "${aws_instance.name.public_ip}"
#   cidr_blocks = ["${formatlist("%v/32", aws_instance.name.public_ip)}"] 
#   cidr_blocks = [aws_instance.name.public_ip,"32"]
#   cidr_blocks = ["${aws_instance.name.public_ip}/32"]    
#   cidr_blocks = join("/",[aws_instance.kibana.public_ip,"32"])
#   cidr_blocks = ["${aws_instance.kibana.public_ip}/32"]
```

SG

```
resource "aws_security_group" "elasticsearch_sg" {
 
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.elastic_vpc.id
  ingress {
    description = "ingress rules"
    cidr_blocks = [var.access_ip] # my IP
    from_port = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 22
  }


  ingress {
    description = "ingress rules2"
#    cidr_blocks = "${aws_instance.kibana.public_ip}"
#   cidr_blocks = [aws_instance.kibana.public_ip,"32"]
#   cidr_blocks = ["${aws_instance.kibana.public_ip}/32"]    
    from_port = 9200
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 9300
    self = true
  }
  
  egress {
    description = "egress rules"
    cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
    from_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    to_port = 0
  }
  tags={
    Name="elasticsearch_sg"
  }
}
```

---------null_resource start_es

```
resource "null_resource" "start_es" {
  depends_on = [ 
    null_resource.move_elasticsearch_file
  ]
  count = 3
  connection {
     type = "ssh"
     user = "ec2-user"
     private_key = "${tls_private_key.pk.private_key_pem}"
     host= aws_instance.elastic_nodes[count.index].public_ip
  }
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum update -y",
      "sudo rpm -i https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.5.1-x86_64.rpm",
      "sudo systemctl daemon-reload",
      "sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service",
#      "sudo sed -i 's@-Xms1g@-Xms${aws_instance.elastic_nodes[count.index].root_block_device[0].volume_size/2}g@g' /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options",
#      "sudo sed -i 's@-Xmx1g@-Xmx${aws_instance.elastic_nodes[count.index].root_block_device[0].volume_size/2}g@g' /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options",
      "sudo rm /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml",
      "sudo cp elasticsearch.yml /etc/elasticsearch/",
      "sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service"
    ]
  }
}
```

aws_instance.kibana

```
resource "aws_instance" "kibana" {
  depends_on = [ 
    null_resource.start_es
   ]
  ami                    = "ami-04d29b6f966df1537"
  instance_type          = "t2.medium"
  iam_instance_profile   = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.test_profile.name}"
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.elastic_subnet[var.az_name[0]].id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.kibana_sg.id]
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.kp.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  tags = {
    Name = "kibana"
  }
}
```

aws_security_group.elasticsearch_sg

```
resource "aws_security_group" "elasticsearch_sg" {
 
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.elastic_vpc.id
  ingress {
    description = "ingress rules"
    cidr_blocks = [var.access_ip] # my IP
    from_port = 22
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 22
  }


  ingress {
    description = "ingress rules2"
#    cidr_blocks = "${aws_instance.kibana.public_ip}"
#   cidr_blocks = [aws_instance.kibana.public_ip,"32"]
#   cidr_blocks = ["${aws_instance.kibana.public_ip}/32"]    
    from_port = 9200
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 9300
    self = true
  }
  
  egress {
    description = "egress rules"
    cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
    from_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    to_port = 0
  }
  tags={
    Name="elasticsearch_sg"
  }
}
```

aws_instance.elastic_nodes

```
resource "aws_instance" "elastic_nodes" {
  count = 3
  ami                    = "ami-04d29b6f966df1537"
  instance_type          = "t2.medium"
  iam_instance_profile   = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.test_profile.name}"
  subnet_id              = aws_subnet.elastic_subnet[var.az_name[count.index]].id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.elasticsearch_sg.id]
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.kp.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  tags = {
    Name = "elasticsearch_${count.index}"
  }
}
```

null_resource.move_elasticsearch_file

```
resource "null_resource" "move_elasticsearch_file" {
  depends_on = [aws_instance.elastic_nodes]
  count = 3
  connection {
     type = "ssh"
     user = "ec2-user"
     private_key = "${tls_private_key.pk.private_key_pem}"
     host= aws_instance.elastic_nodes[count.index].public_ip
  } 
  provisioner "file" {
#    content = data.template_file.init_elasticsearch[count.index].rendered
    content = templatefile("./templates/elasticsearch_config.tpl", {
    cluster_name = "cluster1"
        node_name = "node_${count.index}"
        node = aws_instance.elastic_nodes[count.index].private_ip
        node1 = aws_instance.elastic_nodes[0].private_ip
        node2 = aws_instance.elastic_nodes[1].private_ip
        node3 = aws_instance.elastic_nodes[2].private_ip
  })
    destination = "elasticsearch.yml"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the entire SG rule block?

Comment: @MarkoE -- yes, updated

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is the issue? When you do e.g., `cidr_blocks = ["${aws_instance.kibana.public_ip}/32"]` does it show up as expected in the AWS console or are there any errors?

Comment: @MarkoE -- ``` Error: Cycle: aws_instance.elastic_nodes, null_resource.move_elasticsearch_file, null_resource.start_es, aws_instance.kibana, aws_security_group.elasticsearch_sg```

Comment: Uhm, there are cyclic dependencies in your code. Can you add the relevant parts?

Comment: @MarkoE ----Okay

Comment: @MarkoE --- Perhaps I need to create a single ingress rule and then, when attach to elasticsearch_sg. I will try that.

Comment: Ok, so this cannot work as you are referencing the SG in the EC2 instance resource and you are also referencing the value of the public IP attribute in the SG resource, which is causing the cyclic dependency error.

Comment: @MarkoE --- So, yes, you are absolutely right. It works!!!. I got a pub ip in SG. Thanks for pushing me to answer.